# How to manage files with a batchscript via "Send To"?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I want to improve my file managent and need some help to get started.
For this specific script, my idea is the following:

while in Explorer
rightclick a file -> Send To -> "Apps[.bat]"

Then the script starts and does the following:

1. moves **the whole directory** (and subfolders) of the selected file to a specified location (in my case C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Apps\Files)
   *so sending Name\Downloads\Coolportableapplication\Coolapp.exe to the batch results in Name\Desktop\Apps\Files\Coolportableapplication\Coolapp.exe*
2. creates a shortcut of *C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Apps\Files\Coolportableapplication\Coolapp.exe* in *C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Apps*

Is this generally possible with a batchscript?
This isn't my first batch but I've never dealt with unspecified files and English isn't my native language so I couldn't really find anything useful for my cause, though I am sure my little script won't be too much of a problem for you. Based on that batch, I want to create similar scripts but I just have no idea how to begin with that one.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show your own efforts! Asking for a full script is off-topic here; SO is not a free code writing service!

Answer (score 0):

No need for a batch file but anyway.

1: Type `shell:sendto` into your explorer window and copy the shortcut to your directory "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Apps\Files". This directory will now show as default in your *Send To* options.